# google cloud vm cannot find GPU after restart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu

I created one google cloud vm with GPU. The GPU was working after instance created.
But after restarting the vm, the GPU was gone.

I ran nvidia-smi and got this error:
*NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.*

Who knows how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: It could be related to the driver version compatibility, What is the output of `sudo nvidia-smi` and `sudo lspci | grep -i "nvidia"` ? take a look in [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu#minimum-driver) ensure that you are running a valid version. Also you may want to run the script `/usr/bin/nvidia-bug-report.sh` this may help to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @rriovall 
`sudo nvidia-smi`   

**NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.**

Comment: @rriovall  `sudo lspci | grep -i "nvidia"` returns 
** 00:04.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104GL [Tesla T4] (rev a1) **

Comment: @rriovall run nvidia-bug-report and got this 
**Error: nvmlInit(): Driver Not Loaded**  
Not sure why the driver was gone after restarting.

Comment: Can you share the out put of `nvidia-bug-report.sh`? it generates a `nvidia-bug-report.log.gz` log file

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using a Google Deep Learning VM with CUDA 11.3 this solved it:

```
sudo /opt/deeplearning/install-driver.sh
```

Not sure is a definitive solution but works for now.

There seems to be some issue with the kernel headers not being found, couldn't figure it out exactly.